# Programmatically searching GMail?

Tags: api, search, gmail

Is there any way to programmatically search GMail, preferably using C#?

For example, I'd like to get all email messages matching the search *label:MyLabel from:no_reply@foo.bar*, so that I can parse the email bodies as required.

The only thing remotely feasible I've found is the [GMail API](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gmail-api/) by [Johnvey Hwang](http://www.johnvey.com/features/gmailapi/), though it doesn't look like it supports searching email and also hasn't been updated in many years either.

In any case, I haven't had much luck in getting it to even connect to my account so far, and was wondering if this even works anymore?

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Comment: @Kiquenet The project is on Github.  However, I ended up not implementing any search functionality, but if you're interested in seeing the code anyway, it's at https://github.com/munr/iDeviceAppReporter.

Comment: @Kiquenet Actually, looking at this again, it seems like I did implement search after all.  https://github.com/munr/iDeviceAppReporter/blob/master/ReportingApp/MainForm.cs#L143

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually, I settled with using [IMAPX](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b2521818-5a75-4295-8e67-97712ca3073d/), which works pretty well.  Tried a few other IMAP libraries which weren't as powerful and seemed a bit flaky.

If anyone's interested, the outcome of this is [iDevice App Reporter](https://github.com/munr/iDeviceAppReporter), which is a WinForms app that searches GMail (or any other IMAP mailbox) for iTunes app receipts and parses these to return a list of downloaded/purchased apps from the Apple AppStore.

Answer (score 8):

Create an IMAP client, [or use a library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/imaplibrary.aspx), to access Gmail and search for e-mail messages. The IMAP protocol explicitly supports searching on the server-side. [Make sure IMAP access is enabled for the Gmail account.](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=77695)

Note that in Gmail, [labels are treated like IMAP folders.](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=77657)

Answer (score 2):

it's 2015 now! You can use [Google's Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filtering).

It has a search feature, you can do it easily just like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q="in:sent after:2014/01/01 before:2014/01/30"
```

Comment: The Gmail API has a bug, it's going to be fixed soon, hopefully: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4608

Answer (score 1):

To use a full gmail search (like multi labels, boolean operators) via IMAP, you need to use **X-GM-RAW** attribute. More on [Google Apps docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/imap_extensions#extension_of_the_search_command_x-gm-raw).