# Searching mails in a Google mail account?

Tags: php, gmail, google-api

I want to look for mails in my Google mail account that match a certain search term. The plan is to give it a search term and search any mails subject, sender and body. I know how to browse through all the mail and I am sure I can get the data I want and match that with my search term using some regex, but is there a better way?

Maybe there is an API or something better I could use? I am doing this with PHP.

Comment: You may look into [Programatically searching GMail?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242619/programatically-searching-gmail) for some directions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every Gmail account can be accessed via IMAP and there is an [IMAP PHP extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php). However, Google provides IMAP extensions with additional functionality. The documentation can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/imap_extensions).